# Can I use one SSL Certificate across all Sandboxes?

Tags: api, integration, ssl

I need to call an external API from Salesforce. I have 3 different sandboxes (Dev, QA, Training) that point to the same external QA API endpoint.
Is it possible to create a single CA signed certificate and use it across my 3 sandboxes?
Should I create an individual certificate for each of the sandboxes?
My domain for dev sandbox would be mycompany--dev.cs7.my.salesforce.com as of now when I get the certificate signed. What will happen if Salesforce switches my sandboxes from one instance to another later on (example CS7 to CS20)?
Please suggest/share your experience.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Though it may not be correct security-wise. I was able to use the same cert for testing purpose and it worked.